# Multiple Extenders in Knockout JS not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just finding my way in KO, so please be gentle!

Individually each extender works, but when i chain them, the first one (reset) doesnt fire.

**Javascript:**

```
ko.extenders.reset = function (target) {
    var initialValue = target();

    target.reset = function () {
        target(initialValue);
    }

    return target;
}
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {
    //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target, //always return the original observables value
        write: function (newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(+newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({
        notify: 'always'
    });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};

function AppViewModel(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({
        reset: true

    });
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last).extend({
        reset: true,
        numeric: 0
    });
    self.resetAll = function () {
        for (key in self) {
            if (ko.isObservable(self[key]) && typeof self[key].reset == 'function') {
                self[key].reset()
            }
        }
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

**HTML:**

```
1 extender (works):<input data-bind='value: firstName' /><br>
2 extenders (doesnt work)<input data-bind='value: lastName' /><br>
<input type="button" value="Reset All" data-bind="click:resetAll" id="ResetInvoiceButton" />
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/vk4x2/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your `numeric` extender returns a new computed the order of your extenders **does matter**.

In your current setup your `reset` extender runs first and it adds the reset function to your original observable but then the `numeric` runs so it overrides your "reset enhanced" observable with a completely new computed observable.

So you just need to execute your extenders in the correct order:

```
this.lastName = ko.observable(last)
                  .extend({ numeric: 0 })
                  .extend({ reset: true });
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8yZj/).

Note that if you want to have a specific order for your extenders you need to apply them in separate `extend` calls otherwise the execution order is not guarantied to be in the order of the properties.