# What order are knockout js observable extensions executed?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

At the bottom of the knockoutjs docs for [extending observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) it states...

> More than one extender can be applied in a single call to the .extend method of an observable.
>
> ```
> this.firstName = ko.observable(first).extend({ required: "Please enter a first name", logChange: "first name" });
> ```
>
> In this case, both the required and logChange extenders would be executed against our observable.

... I want to know what order the extensions will be executed in. Will it always execute in the same order? What definesd the order?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831840/multiple-extenders-in-knockout-js-not-working, at least the answer also applies to here.

Comment: yep - the accepted answer there answers my question too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20835989/665261 thanks!

Comment: Actually, I think that's a different question, and that answer answers the different question. The crux of that question is chaining the extenders, which you're not doing above.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't articulate my problem well enough, or perhaps I had a bit of an A/B problem. The crux of my issue is that if extensions can execute in different orders, then results may vary between executions (producing bugs and erratic tests). I would also like to control the order of execution so as to choose what sequence the extensions make their manipulations. Both problems are solved for me in the linked to answer.

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to ask "How do I make sure these happen in a given order," that's what you should have asked. I answered the question you actually asked.

Comment: Yes, if I could turn back the hands of time, I would have asked that. At the time, I did not know if there was already a mechanism in place to order them. As I recall, your answer initially could not say for sure, speculating knockout did no sorting before executing the extensions. Pointing out the knockout source implementation does address my questions, which is why I up-voted the answer, but as I said, does not solve my underlying problem, which is that I want to control the order. If my question was about javascript object iteration order, you should have voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order is important, you can call `extend` multiple times:

```
this.firstName = ko.observable(first)
    .extend({ required: "Please enter a first name" })
    .extend({ logChange: "first name" });
```

That being said, browsers generally process an object's properties in the same order they were defined. Thus your original method will have the same effect as this one.

Answer (score 4):

The order is undefined in the current Knockout (3.4.0 as of this writing), because JavaScript object properties **had** no defined order prior to ES2015, and even in ES2015, `for-in` and `Object.keys` have no order.

The current Knockout loops through those extenders like this:

```
function applyExtenders(requestedExtenders) {
    var target = this;
    if (requestedExtenders) {
        ko.utils.objectForEach(requestedExtenders, function(key, value) {
            var extenderHandler = ko.extenders[key];
            if (typeof extenderHandler == 'function') {
                target = extenderHandler(target, value) || target;
            }
        });
    }
    return target;
}
```

Its `objectForEach` function uses `for-in`:

```
function objectForEach(obj, action) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            action(prop, obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

So, there is no defined order in which the extenders will run (even on ES2015) in the current Knockout.

**In theory**, a future version of Knockout could use the new [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.getownpropertynames) instead:

```
function applyExtenders(requestedExtenders) {
    var target = this;
    if (requestedExtenders) {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(requestedExtenders).forEach(function(key) {
            var extenderHandler = ko.extenders[key];
            if (typeof extenderHandler == 'function') {
                target = extenderHandler(target, requestedExtenders[key]) || target;
            }
        });
    }
    return target;
}
```

`getOwnPropertyNames` respects the newly-defined order of JavaScript properties, listed in [§9.1.12](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys) of the spec. In your example, that would be `required`, then `logChange`, because object initializers create properties in lexical order, and the order of "own" properties with names that are not all-numeric and not `Symbol`s is the order of creation (but see the spec for details).